# Electron Google Login: "This browser or app may not be secure"

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api, electron, google-oauth

Google Logins have usually favored mainstream browsers, and so until now, to get it to work on Electron you would need to change the `userAgent` string to Chrome. However, after getting reports from users last week, **I found that this no longer works**.

Opening a Google signin URL using the following code:

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  height: 600,
  width: 800
})
const client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  clientId, clientSecret, "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
)
const url = client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: "offline",
  scope: scopes
})
win.loadURL(url, {
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 Edg/93.0.961.52"
})
```

This still yields the `This browser or app may not be secure` error and prevents Google signin from working.

I'm hoping there is a solution to getting Google signin working on Electron again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be some tricks to work this around, but they will most likely be blocked by Google, eventually. They did give head-ups about this in Google Developer blog:

- [Upcoming security changes to Google's OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint in embedded webviews"](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html).

The proper solution is to use the user's default browser for OAuth2 authorization flow UI (rather than a custom WebView popup), as required by ["RFC8252: OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252):

> OAuth 2.0 authorization requests from native apps should only be
> made    through external user-agents, primarily the user's browser.
> This    specification details the security and usability reasons why
> this is    the case and how native apps and authorization servers can
> implement    this best practice.

One good reason for this is that the user might already be *authenticated* with Google in their default browser, so they don't have to enter the password / go through MFA flow once again. They would only see the *authorization* request for your specific app, which they may decide to approve or reject.

One other good reason is that they could use a password manager of their choice, which most likely works with their default browser but not with your Electron app.